# How do i get a guild by its invite link? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've been looking all over the internet and I can't find a answer to my question,

I am trying to get a guild by it's invite link, so like I have a discord invite link such as https://discord.com/invite/ainvitecodegoeshere, Now I want my discord.js bot to get it's guild ID with using only the invite code, Is that possible? If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I know its a pretty old post, but you can get the guild ID trough the discord api. You can find a link to the documentation [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/invite)

If you have the invite link, you can use the api by fetching [https://discord.com/api/invites/[code]](https://discord.com/api/invites/%5Bcode%5D) where [code] is the invite code.
It will return some guild information including the guild ID, even if your bot is not in it. To get the guild object, you can use:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guildID')
```

Comment: Adding on: The guild may need to be fetched, No guarantee that it will be in the cache

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Invite = "InviteCode"; // Example: bM2Ae2

client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { // Looping through all the guilds your bot is in.
    guild.fetchInvites().then(invites => { // Fetching the invites of the guild.
        invites.forEach(invite => { // Looping through all the invites of the guild.
            if (invite.code == Invite) { // Checking if the invite code matches.
                message.channel.send(`Found guild : ${guild.name} | ${guild.id}`);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

---

I'd personally use a plain loop instead since you cannot stop the `.forEach()` loop, and it'll continue to loop through guilds even after it finds the guild you're looking for.

Note: Your bot must be in  the guild you want to find.

Comment: But my bot is not in the guild

Comment: Then you can't do it.

Comment: Error - `guild.fetchInvites` is not a function

Comment: @cocobar Use [`guild.invites.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildInviteManager)