# How do i make my Bot list every Invite from my Servers (more info in question)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i've been trying to do a invites Command which should find all Invites from the Servers my Bot is on.
(ONLY MY OWN SERVERS)
I do have tried some ideas and code but nothing worked, how to implement it into my Discord Embed i do already know i just need help with the Invite Listing.

````
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    guild.fetchInvites().then(guildInvites => {
        invites[invites.length + 1] = (guild + " - `Invites: " + guildInvites.array().join(", ") + "`");
        ct++;
        if(ct >= client.guilds.size) {
            invites.forEach((invite, i) => {
                if(invite == undefined)
                    invites.splice(i, 1);
            }); 
            invites.shift();
            invites.forEach((invite, i) => invites[i] = "- " + invite);
            invites = invites.join("\n\n");
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("All Invites:")
            .setDescription(invites);
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    })
});```

Help is much appreciated.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you caching your servers before fetching them? The cache is necessary so the bot can get information from each guild that it is in. Change the first line to

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(() => {
  // ...
}
```

Got this code from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838854/how-do-i-get-a-guild-by-its-invite-link-discord-js).

Comment: Hey, i tried to do this now but there came the Error that Cache is undefined. 
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')`

Comment: Do you define the client at all?

Answer (score 0):

From the previous answers and comments on them, I can guess that you either don't have the required intents when instantiating the `client` class, OR that maybe your `client` class is not correctly defined.

How do you define client? If it's from another file, try importing it correctly. Don't make multiple clients from a same token/process.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.guilds.cache.map(guild => {

            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("All Invites:")



 guild.channels.cache
            .first()
            .createInvite()
            .then((invite) => embed.setDescription(invites.url);)
            .catch(() => embed.setDescription("Lien d'invitation", "Permission Invalides"));
            message.channel.send(embed);
})
```